# TypeScript, node.js development with Visual Studio 2012 express

Tags: visual-studio, node.js, typescript, tsc

How can I write, build and run a node.js app in Visual Studio? I install the TypeScript extension on VS and the node.js package. When I create new project of type TypeScript it is only able to write script for browsers only.

**Update**

I want autocomplete and error handling for node.js libraries

Comment: Check out NodeJS support in WebMatrix 2 and 3 http://www.microsoft.com/web/webmatrix/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to include a [type definition for node.js](https://github.com/soywiz/typescript-node-definitions/blob/master/node.d.ts).

This file declares all of the operations for node.js so you can get auto-completion and type safety.

```
/// <reference path="./node.d.ts" />

var x = new SlowBuffer(5);
```

Comment: Thank you, i try it. How about Sublime Text 2? This will work in ST2 too?

Comment: I am not certain, so may be corrected, but I think Sublime has syntax-highlighting. I don't think it has auto-completion or static-analysis for TypeScript (yet).

Comment: You can get node intellisense in Sublime Text 2 using this package/plugin: https://github.com/Kronuz/SublimeCodeIntel

Answer (score 1):

You can just use VS as an editor, there's no need for solution files or anything.

To create a node.js app first install the typescript package:

```
npm install -g typescript
```

Then compile your file into javascript:

```
tsc app.ts
```

Run your app as a node process:

```
node app.js
```

Comment: But i want autocomplete and error handling for node.js libraries.

Comment: Absolutely. Without completion there's little sense in using VS.